# Asp.Net MVC OnSessionStart event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I have found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560084/session-variables-in-asp-net-mvc/560115#560115) which describes a very interesting OnSessionStart event, but I am unable to "hook" it up (whatever it means) to my global.asax.cs. I am also unsuccessful while searching the web for it. So could someone please explain to me, if the event really exists in asp.net mvc, where do I get it (inherit or what from where) and where do I put it?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

It looks like this:

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // your code here, it will be executed upon session start
}
```

It does work in Asp.net MVC.
Put it as a method in the class defined in Global.asax.cs, for example just after the RegisterRoutes method.

Comment: Link is broken. Here is another which gives similar info: http://sandblogaspnet.blogspot.com/2008/03/methods-in-globalasax.html