# Get/Set HttpContext Session Methods in BaseController vs Mocking HttpContextBase to create Get/Set methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, httpcontext

### I created Get/Set HttpContext Session Methods in BaseController class and also Mocked HttpContextBase and created Get/Set methods.

Which is the best way to use it.

```
    HomeController : BaseController
    {
        var value1 = GetDataFromSession("key1") 
        SetDataInSession("key2",(object)"key2Value");

        Or

        var value2 = SessionWrapper.GetFromSession("key3");
        GetFromSession.SetDataInSession("key4",(object)"key4Value");
    }
```

---

```
   public class BaseController : Controller
   {
       public  T GetDataFromSession<T>(string key)
       {
          return (T) HttpContext.Session[key];
       }

       public void SetDataInSession(string key, object value)
       {
          HttpContext.Session[key] = value;
       }
   }
```

### Or

```
  public class BaseController : Controller
  {
     public ISessionWrapper SessionWrapper { get; set; }

     public BaseController()
     {
       SessionWrapper = new HttpContextSessionWrapper();
     }
  }

  public interface ISessionWrapper
  {
     T GetFromSession<T>(string key);
   void    SetInSession(string key, object value);
  }

  public class HttpContextSessionWrapper : ISessionWrapper
  {
     public  T GetFromSession<T>(string key)
     {
        return (T) HttpContext.Current.Session[key];
     }

     public void SetInSession(string key, object value)
     {
         HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = value;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The second one seems the best. Although I would probably write those two as extension methods to the [HttpSessionStateBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpsessionstatebase.aspx) instead of putting them into a base controller. Like this:

```
public static class SessionExtensions
{
    public static T GetDataFromSession<T>(this HttpSessionStateBase session, string key)
    {
         return (T)session[key];
    }

    public static void SetDataInSession<T>(this HttpSessionStateBase session, string key, object value)
    {
         session[key] = value;
    }
}
```

and then inside the controllers, or helpers, or something that has an instance of `HttpSessionStateBase` use it:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Session.SetDataInSession("key1", "value1");
    string value = Session.GetDataFromSession<string>("key1");
    ...
}
```

Writing session wrappers is useless in ASP.NET MVC as the `HttpSessionStateBase` provided by the framework is already an abstract class which could be easily mocked in unit tests.

Comment: I fixed a typo via edit but then the all-wise rejected it. See if you can find it ;)

Answer (score 5):

Just a little correction for the SetDataInSession method of the latest post. In my opinion, it´s a elegant solution! Thanks Darin Dimitrov.

```
public static class SessionExtensions
{
 public static T GetDataFromSession<T>(this HttpSessionStateBase session, string key) {
            return (T)session[key];
        }

        public static void SetDataInSession(this HttpSessionStateBase session, string key, object value) {
            session[key] = value;
        }
}
```

- First create this class, and after remember to refer its namespace in the Controller class that will call this methods.
- When getting the session value:

`string value = Session.GetDataFromSession<string>("key1");`

The  must be a compatible type with the object persisted in the session.