# Session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, session-variables

Hello I am looking to use a session variable in MVC 3 C# to store a user Id, so that the user doesn't have to enter their user id on create form

Where should I put the code for the session variable, if not in the global.asax file?
i know the code looks something like

```
    Session["userId"]
```

I have seen examples using the global.asax but it is very confusing.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Presumably you have some kind of login process? You would normally associate a userid with some opaque token (i.e. the user's auth cookie) at *that* point...?

Comment: This has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560084/session-variables-in-asp-net-mvc I hope it helps, happy coding!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Session variables in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560084/session-variables-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: You might consider putting the id in the Forms authentication ticket and creating a custom `IIdentity` that has an Id property on it. Usually though, you would identify a user via the `Name` property on the `IIdentity` (which is what Membership providers do)

Comment: @Hiral an "answer" that consists **only** of a link to another stackoverflow post is not really an answer; either a "close as duplicate" vote or a comment is usually more appropriate

Comment: Thanks Marc, will keep that in mind next time. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `Session` object in your controllers.

Whether you *should* is a different question - depending on `Session` will make your code difficult to test.

Comment: I'd go further and say that session is always evil.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I agree that it makes it any more difficult to test since Session property on a controller is of type `HttpSessionStateBase` which is easy to fake. It is an additional dependency for sure though.

Comment: Whether session is evil or not, explain to me how to build a login banking enterprise website that needs to be 508 compliant and degrade gracefully thus not relying on javascript or cookies that doesn't use sessions.  I am not seeing another option when the requirements are to popup warnings at 15 minutes and log person out at 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning on using that later on in a few places, a good place to put that in place is in the login part so that you know if a user is logged in the session varaibale is set. You can then access it from any controller if the user is logged in