# ASP.NET MVC 4 ViewBag value incremented only once

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, viewbag

Hy!

I have a very interesting problem. I have a button and if a user clicks on that button it will reload that page, incrementing the value which is stored in the viewbag and write it on the screen. When the user clicks on the button, the value of the number incremented only once and I don't know why. The codes are very simple:

The controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
         ViewBag.number= 0;
         return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int number)
{
            ViewBag.number= number;
           return View();
}
```

The view:

```
@{

    int number= ViewBag.number;
    number++;

}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Default", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Hidden("number",number)
    @Html.Display("number",number);
    <input type="submit" value="Ok" />
}
```

Thanks for your reply! :)

Comment: ViewBag will be scoped to request.

Comment: You can't do that with ViewBag, because ViewBag is meant for sharing data just for one request. You can try with SessionObject. http://stackoverflow.com/a/560115/1081079

Comment: The code seems pretty sound at first glance.  No reason ViewBag can't be used in this manner.

Comment: To store data between requests use session or TempData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ViewBag** is supposed to be used to pass data from controller to view (dynamic alternative of **ViewData**).To store data between requests use **session** or **TempData**

Comment: Thank you all for your fast help! :) I using TempData["number"] and it's working! :)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't see any issue with your code.

However, If you replace your code on view to below, I think this should work.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

    <input type="hidden" name="number" value="@number" />
    @Html.Display("number", number)
    <input type="submit" value="Ok" />
}
```

But not sure what is the difference between the Html.Hidden and directly writing the input tag.