# Set global variable from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new in .net mvc, I am working on Visual Studio 2012. I just want to fetch data from database's table in controller and store this value into different variable. For example:

```
public class TestController
{
   public ActionResult TestMethod()
   {
      var model = some LINQ code;
   }
}
```

Now I just want to store this `model` value into different variable such as `string`, `int` etc depend on the necessary.

Comment: you need to add more context.what are you trying to do? why do you need a global variable

Comment: yes, I want to set this LINQ result in global variable as well as Session variable

Comment: So, what's problem do you experience with it?

Comment: Perhaps an [Entity Framework Quickstart Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb399182(v=vs.100).aspx) or an [ADO.Net Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx(v=vs.110).aspx) might help.

Comment: I am trying to set user IP address which must be matched from database and use this IP address in the whole application

Comment: Take a look [at this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7541043/1177964), if you want an example of how to store variable in `Session` object

Comment: What is your problem exactly? is it how to store data in `session`? or how to fetch data from `database` by `LINQ`?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to learn more about **mvc 4**. There are lots of tutorial in internet. [check this out](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4)

Here are some sample code ::

In your Controller :

```
 public class testController
 {       
      public ActionResult testMethod()
      {
          ViewBag.someData = // get data from database using Linq or SQL Query
          // or you can use Model/ModelView
          return View(model)
      }    
 }
```

In you View (cshtml) ::

```
@{
    var someData = ViewBag.someData; // now you can use this data in your cshtml file
}
```