# how to write once Session["prevUrl"] for whole application

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax, web.config-transform

how to avoid writing this page load code in all pages of application ?
can we write this in global.asax file?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Session["prevUrl"] = Request.Url;
  string PreviousUrl = Session["prevUrl"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/560115/3793448) it should give you a good understanding

Answer (score 1):

No. Global.asax is only initializing when the application is starting. My suggestion is to create a base class for your pages to inherit from.

```
public class CommonPage: Page
{
    public CommonPage()
    {
        this.Load += Page_Load;
    }

    private void Page_Load
    {
        Session["prevUrl"] = Request.Url;
    }
}
```

Comment: how to create base class ? do u mean i have to add one class in app_code ? @Rickard

Comment: Check this guide to learn about inheritance: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_inheritance.htm