# how to build a graph in asp.net mvc application once and access it on susequent requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-structures, architecture

I am building an asp.net MVC application which searches a graph data structure to fulfill user's requests. I want to build this graph data structure on first request from database and then on requests after first request I want to use the previously built graph rather than building it again.

but I do not know where to store the graph on first request so it can be accessed on subsequent requests.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could consider storing it in your DB, and this would require you to store your graph in two separate tables: one for *Nodes* and one for *Paths*. You should have *start_node_id* and *end_node_id* in *Paths*, both being foreign keys referring to *Nodes*. As nodes can be connected with variable numbers of nodes, I believe creating multiple columns referring neigbouring nodes in *Nodes* makes no sense at all, as it would mean lots of NULL neighbours and limiting maximum neighbours count.

Comment: i do not want to built the graph in db. the graph should be loaded in memory to run search on it

Comment: Do you want your graph to exist as long as session is not terminated only? If so, you may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560084/session-variables-in-asp-net-mvc) thread interesting.